# Hey how would I put this button in the center?

Tags: html, css, button, center, html-helper

[Picture of My Website[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sNp7.png)

Hey so if you see that image there then I just wanted to know how to put the button in the center, like how the heading is. Like directly under it, text-align does not work for me.

Please let me know if anything in my code is preventing the button from going in the center.
(I am new to HTML)

My code :

```
<html style = "background-color: lightblue;">
<b
  ><h1 id="chimp">
    Welcome to Monkey Idle!
  </h1></b
>
<a class="button" href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: black" id = "button">
  Click Here to Play!
</a>
<a id="button2" class="button" href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">
  Played before? Click here!
</a>
<style>
  #chimp {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: cursive;
  }
  #moneycount {
    border-style: solid;
  }
  #button2 {
  text-align: center;
  background color;
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: cursive;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    position: center;
    align: center;

  }
  @keyframes buttonbounce {
    0%{margin-left: 0px;}
    100%{margin-left: 10px;}
  }
  #button2:hover {
        animation: buttonbounce 0.1s infinite;
  }
  #button {
      text-align: center;
  background color;
    position:relative;
    
    font-family: cursive;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;

  }
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Research for it

Answer (score 0):

The reason that text-align doesn't work for buttons is that buttons are not considered to be text. When you use text-align, you are centering the text within the parent element, not necessarily the center of the page. Text-align on a button for example will just center the text at the center of the button. If you want to center the button, you can wrap the button in a div, and utilize [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). If you are getting started on web development, I highly recommend the aforementioned Flexbox as well as [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) for page layouts.

```css
#button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="button-wrapper">
  <button>My button!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey so I have another question, when I do that it makes the width of the background color very long. When I change the width it goes back to the left. How would I fix that?

Comment: In the example I provided, the parent div, (#button-wrapper) will stretch across the width of the screen. Simply change the styling on #button-wrapper to be whatever background color you desire so it doesn't look like it exists.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not understanding. Mind posting an example?

Comment: I can't post another example as a comment, I would need to make another response. You're welcome to open up another question, but the takeaway that would be the most important for you is to either read more documentation, watch videos, or take online courses on the subject matter. I can tell from the code that you shared that you're quite new, which is totally fine, but you're writing quite a lot of CSS to achieve a very small amount of styling. The more CSS you write, the more the stylings with interfere with each other, and it's going to be very difficult for a beginner to debug.

Comment: Here is a fantastic course I took when I began to learn CSS: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Here is a great Youtuber who makes videos exclusively on CSS content: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJZv4d5rbIKd4QHMPkcABCw

Comment: Yes that is cool, but I still need help with that code. Example maybe?